# How do i get an image to resize to a responsive div container?

Tags: responsive-design

I am trying to get my image to expand to the width of the responsive div container it is in.
here is the css

```
.row {
  height: 453px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#one img{
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Here i s the html

```
<div id="one" class="row">
    <img src="images/home_img2.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 .responsiveImage {max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;}
</style>

<img src="images/home_img2.png" class="responsiveImage" />
```

Comment: I gave it a go and the image is responsive but the container it is in is not.. I found if i put the image in without the div tag and set the with to 100% it did what I wanted :)

Comment: is the div inside something else constraining its' width?